# How to install different fonts in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, fonts

Is there any application which can let me browse different font styles and install what I have liked from Internet?

Answer (score 2):

Type catcher is an application which let you browse through all the fonts styles available and let you install what you like . to install that open your terminal and type as

**For Ubuntu 13.04 , Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrewsomething/typecatcher
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install typecatcher
```

after that just open it and browse the fonds and install what you like.

**For Ubuntu 13.10**

No need to add PPA for that, you can install it directly from the terminal or software center.

from terminal you can use the command as

```
sudo apt-get install typecatcher
```

installing font is very simple and easy , just select the font you want and check the preview. if you like it just select download and then you can use it.

[image]
hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Browse fonts at http://fontzone.net/ and download one you like (should be a .ttf file).

Find the file in Files, right click and choose "Open with Font Viewer".

In Font Viewer, click on Install.

The font is then available for applications, e.g. LibreOffice Writer.

Advantage of this method: no additional software to install.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for adding answer but are those fonts can be possible apply to system settings ? I mean themes etc ; Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can - install the unity-tweak-tool and you can use the fonts installed this way within your themes.

Comment: I have added image for your answer , hope you dont mind.