# How can I make Palatino look good in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts

I'm looking at [a website](http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/statnested.html) that attempts to display text in the Palatino font. This is not installed on my system. I'm not sure if it's even possible to get it in Linux. (FWIW I have `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` installed.)

In any case, the fallback font rendered horribly in Firefox, as shown in the screenshot.

[image: palantino in firefox]

As you can see, the height of characters vary. For example, in "enslave", the `a` is shorter than the `v`. This page renders fine in Chromium. I found an [old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gsfonts/+bug/269226) that was supposedly fixed three years ago, so I'm not sure if it's something odd with my system, or just a regression.

How can I fix this problem?

==EDIT==

I already have `texlive-fonts-recommendedtexlive-fonts-recommended` installed on my system, which supposedly contains Palatino, but I can't find it in Font Manager.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/338703/how-to-install-different-fonts-in-ubuntu

Comment: @rajagenupula Thanks for the link. I've added more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is a hinting issue. Try putting this into a new file in `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d`, like `20-autohint.conf`:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="family">
            <string>URW Bookman L</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
            <bool>true</bool>
        </edit>
    </match>
    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="family">
            <string>URW Chancery L</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
            <bool>true</bool>
        </edit>
    </match>
    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="family">
            <string>URW Gothic L</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
            <bool>true</bool>
        </edit>
    </match>
    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="family">
            <string>URW Palladio L</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
            <bool>true</bool>
        </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

If you have an older system and this doesn't work try putting it into the file `~/.fonts.conf`.

Comment: Great! This did fix it. However, I'm wondering if there is a reason to only enable hinting for some fonts, rather than all? (Also, I had hinting enabled in KDE's system settings, but that doesn't seem to do anything.)

Comment: Ah okay. It seems that enabling hinting for all fonts looks worse for some. In that case, how did you pick these specific fonts?

Comment: These fonts are TeX fonts that come from the URW foundry and need special treatment for hinting, I'm not quite sure why. I don't remember where I came across this solution first, though.

Comment: Okay. I don't understand this 100%, but seems like it makes some sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I've round recently is to install Infinality fonts, which fixes this problem without the [file](https://askubuntu.com/a/434871/53508) mentioned by [Jan Larres](https://askubuntu.com/users/15593/jan-larres). I've now using Arch, but there's no reason it shouldn't work in Ubuntu.