# How to fix the ugly font rendering of "Tex Gyre Pagella" in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts

I believe this to be a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339565/how-can-i-make-palatino-look-good-in-firefox), but the accepted answer is 8+ years old and didn't work for me.

[Here is a website](http://archive.adaic.com/projects/atwork/boeing.html), which wants to use the Palatino font. On my system, this falls back to [Tex Gyre Pagella](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/texgyrepagella/), also called `P052-Roman`. Here is what it looks like, it's immediate that the different letters don't have the same height.

[image: Ugly font]

The answer to the question linked above claims the problem is with hinting, but applying the fix did not work. I also tried to change the font names `URW Palladio L` etc to `P052-Roman` and `Tex Gyre Paella`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-improve-firefox-font-rendering-on-linux maybe see if some of the tweaks here change anything for you

Comment: The only custom fonts I dabble with a barcode fonts so I know nothing about what you are using. But there is a Firefox Add-on that deals with your font family: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/texgyrepagella-math/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did in the end: By trial and error I removed all `P052`-fonts Firefox used. They were located in the folders

```
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/urw-base35
/usr/share/fonts/type1/urw-base35
/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts
```

Now my Firefox correctly loads the TeX Gyre Pagella font, which looks better:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have the (four) Palatino Linotype font (i.e. `.ttf`) files installed and the [web page](http://archive.adaic.com/projects/atwork/boeing.html) that you cited looked pretty normal to me on Firefox, so maybe you can solve this issue by just downloading the Palatino Linotype `.zip` package from a fonts distribution site such as e.g. [Fonts 100](https://fonts100.com/76219%2Fpalatino-linotype.zip), extracting those four Palatino font files (i.e. `pala.ttf`, `palab.ttf`, `palabi.ttf` and `palai.ttf`) to any folder that you want (e.g. `~/Fonts/`), and then installing these files through a font installer such as `gnome-font-viewer` or `fontmatrix`.

The long command below creates a `Fonts` folder in your `home` profile directory (e.g. `/home/red_trumpet/`), downloads the aforementioned `.zip` file to it, extracts the four `.ttf` files from such `.zip` file and then deletes the `.zip` file:

```
if [ ! -d ~/Fonts ] ; then mkdir -p ~/Fonts ; fi ; cd ~/Fonts ; wget https://fonts100.com/76219%2Fpalatino-linotype.zip -O ./pl.zip ; if [ ! -x /bin/unzip ] && [ ! -x /usr/bin/unzip ] ; then sudo apt install unzip -y ; fi ; for i in pala.ttf palab.ttf palabi.ttf palai.ttf ; do unzip -j "pl.zip" "$i" ; done ; rm ./pl.zip
```

If you decide to use `fontmatrix`, install it by running this command on the terminal:

```
sudo apt install fontmatrix -y
```

...and then start `fontmatrix` by running this command:

```
fontmatrix & exit
```

Then, at the `fontmatrix` window, click on **File**, then **Import Files...**, then select those 4 `.ttf` files (`pala.ttf`, `palab.ttf`, `palabi.ttf` and `palai.ttf`) at the folder/directory where you extracted them to (e.g. `~/Fonts`) and then click **Open**. Next, scroll down to *Palatino Linoype* and double-click on it, then click on <kbd>Activation</kbd>, click on <kbd>Activate All</kbd>, then exit `fontmatrix`, restart Firefox and access that [web page](http://archive.adaic.com/projects/atwork/boeing.html) again.

Explaining the four `.ttf` file names:

- `pala.ttf` is the standard ("normal") Palatino Linotype font file.
- `palab.ttf` is the **bold** Palatino Linotype font file.
- `palai.ttf` is the *italic* Palatino Linotype font file.
- `palabi.ttf` is the ***bold italic*** Palatino Linotype font file.

You may also use `fontmatrix` to disable the Tex Gyre Pagella font: just select this font at `fontmatrix` and the click on <kbd>Activation</kbd> and then <kbd>Deactivate All</kbd>.

As a last resource (extreme case), you can always use Firefox to access the `about:config` URL, then look for the `browser.display.use_document_fonts` feature and switch its value from 1 to **0**.

Answer (score -1):

If your final goal is to show the page in clear font, you have the option to override the page fonts as described in details in [this Mozilla support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-fonts-and-colors-websites-use): **Application Menu** > **Settings** > **Fonts and Colors** > **Advanced**
then uncheck "*Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above*".
This way, the page will appear with the font you choose.

On the other hand, if your final goal is to show the page using Tex Gyre font. My suggestion is to install the texgyre font (as in the following code) to make sure nothing broken in the font's files.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install fonts-texgyre
```

I did that in my system (ubuntu-22.04-beta) and the page mentioned looks ok.